# Clarification on Dynamic Xpath for SVG icon

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to get the xpath and click that particular xpath, but xpath keeps on varying(dynamic) like below

```
//*[@id="slipstream_action_bar_widget599"]/dl/dd[2]/span/span/svg
//*[@id="slipstream_action_bar_widget414"]/dl/dd[2]/span/span/svg
```

I need your help to get the xpath on the fly and pass that

Comment: show html structure of svg element and your code trials

Comment: Post your relevant html and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Please try xpath as copied below:

```
//*[contains(@id,"slipstream_action_bar_widget")]/dl/dd[2]/span/span/svg
```

Comment: will this work in robot framework, if so what command should i use as it is expecting exact xpath.I tried Get Element Attribute, it failed

Comment: I am not very familiar with robot framework, however, I this this link might be helpful for you: http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20From%20List

Comment: Click Element  xpath=//*[contains(@id,"slipstream_action_bar_widget")]/dl/dd[2]/span/span/svg

Comment: Hi Brian, Its still failing only.

Comment: Hi Prerna, I tried with driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[contains(@id,"slipstream_action_bar_widget")]/dl/dd[2]/span/span/svg').click(), its throwing error, "unable to locate element", please help

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML structure. We might not be able to help without seeing that.

Comment: <dd class="search_container search"><span class="filter_container collapse_search">
    <input class="filter_input" type="text">
    <span class="search_icon"><svg class="filter_icon"><use href="#icon_search_sm"></use></svg></span>
</span></dd>

Comment: This does not seem to be the relevant HTML. Reasons: 1. I don't see any tag with id `slipstream_action_bar_widget`. 2. input tag is not getting closed anywhere. Please provide the correct HTML.